# Class Library (Standard 2.1 or Core 3.1) : namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found

Tags: .net-standard, .net-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.1

1. New Project , Class Library (.NET Standard)
2. On project, properties, changed from 2.0 to 2.1
3. Modified Class1 :

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

    }
}
```

4. This fixed (correctly?) the IApplicationBuilder red squiggly :
5. However the library project does not compile :
   "Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found ..."

What references should be added for these two interfaces please ?
Or are you only supposed to only ever use these interfaces within the web site project ?

Also same result with a .NET Core 3.1 Class Library.
Visual Studio 16.4.4

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to follow this guide (for migrating 2.2 to 3.0)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

This explains what happened
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749

## Update:

### Net Standard

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<!-- Should work with either if you have sdks installed and do restore -->
<!--<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>-->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

With class file

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### Net Core 3.1

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

With class file

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading your first link, it is explained that is is the otherway round : IHostingEnvironment is being replaced with IWebHostEnvironment.
You can confirm this by adding a two new ASP.NET Core projects : 
the 2.2 Startup.cs contains : Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env); 
whereas the 3.1 project contains : Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

Comment: Ah yes my bad, I will update the answer to avoid confusion

Comment: This answer does not work if you are using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. In order for this to work, you have to switch to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` which also forces you to have a static Program.Main() so it is not an actual class library anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work in a .NET Core 3.1 Class Library project file, but not a .NET Standard 2.1 one :

I added the following to the project file :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now the build succeeds with :

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there a way for a .NET Standard 2.1 Class Library project to support the new IWebHostEnvironment  ?